# How to detect Android Gradle dependencies that have newer versions available?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I manage my Android app and associated modules `Gradle` dependencies using  `Gradle` `ext{}` variables.

for example

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    minSdkVersion = 21
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    supportLibVersion = '1.0.2'

    coreKtx = '1.0.2'
    materialMaterial = "1.0.0"
    legacySupportV4 = "1.0.0"
    recyclerView = "1.0.0"
    lifecycleExtensions = "2.0.0"
    playServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    archLifecycleVersion = '2.0.0'
    roomVersion = '2.1.0-beta01'
    archPagingVersion = '2.1.0'
    archWorkerRuntimeVersion = "1.0.1"
    constraintLayoutVersion = '1.1.3'
    browserVersion = '1.0.0'
    appCompatVersionXXX = '1.1.0-alpha03'
    appCompatVersion = '1.0.2'
```

...

Android studio "*sometimes*" highlights a dependency where a newer version is available, however this doesn't appear to be consistent.

I've tried using Android Studio `Analyze > Run Inspection by Name > Newer Library Versions Available`, however that doesn't work at all.

The version of Android Studio is

```
Android Studio 3.4
Build #AI-183.5429.30.34.5452501, built on April 10, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.4
```

How can I detect out of date library versions in Android Studio consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hector,

Android Studio 3.4 has this screen where you can see updated version of your dependency.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Select Dependencies

In this section, if you see a gray color underline in any dependencies name, that means it has a new update as said above.[Update Underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI2HO.png)